# ReactJS: onMouseEnter fires only if clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I run the code below: I return an array of divs and I want them to change background on mouse enter (hover). Event fires only if I click on it. Is this because I need the div to be selected? I already tried tab index = 0 and tab index = 1!
Thanks a lot for your help!!!

```
class OneView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleEnter = this.handleEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleExit = this.handleExit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      hover: false
    }
  }
  handleEnter(e) {
    this.setState({hover: true});
  }
  handleExit(e) {
     this.setState({hover: false});
  }
  render() {
    var specificStyle = {
      textAlign: 'center',
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor : this.state.hover ? '#111' : '#CCC',
    };
    return(
      <div style={Object.assign(genericStyle, specificStyle)} onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter} onMouseOut={this.handleExit}>
        Test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function GenerateMatrix() {
  var firstMatrix = [];
  var specificStyle = {
    display:"inline-flex",
    flexDirection:'row',
    flex: 1
  };
  for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    firstMatrix.push(<OneView/>);
  }
  return (
    <div style={Object.assign(genericStyle, specificStyle)}>
      {firstMatrix}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of `genericStyle` and using the `specificStyle` only works

```js
class OneView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleEnter = this.handleEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleExit = this.handleExit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      hover: false
    }
  }
  handleEnter(e) {
    this.setState({hover: true});
  }
  handleExit(e) {
     this.setState({hover: false});
  }
  render() {
    var specificStyle = {
      textAlign: 'center',
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor : this.state.hover ? '#111' : '#CCC',
    };
    return(
      <div style={Object.assign(specificStyle)} onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter} onMouseOut={this.handleExit}>
        Test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function GenerateMatrix() {
  var firstMatrix = [];
  var specificStyle = {
    display:"inline-flex",
    flexDirection:'row',
    flex: 1
  };
  for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    firstMatrix.push(<OneView/>);
  }
  return (
    <div style={Object.assign(specificStyle)}>
      {firstMatrix}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<GenerateMatrix/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: what's the reason to have two separate handlers, instead of one? (btw having one gave me some issue with the state firing the event multiple times)

Comment: mouseEnter and mouseOut need to be used together to tell that element is hovered, If you use onMouseOver, it will keep firing till the mouse if hovered on the element